# Meteor Angular2 Tutorial error after adding ui-accounts

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, angular, meteor-accounts

After [section 8](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/user-accounts-authentication-and-permissions) (user accounts) in Meteor Angular 2 tutorial (social app) nothing is shown on the browser and in F12 I get this error:

> install.js:85 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'meteor/accounts-base'require @ install.js:85meteorInstall.node_modules.angular2-meteor-accounts-ui.build.login-buttons.js @ login-buttons.js:13fileEvaluate @ install.js:153require @ install.js:82meteorInstall.node_modules.angular2-meteor-accounts-ui.build.index.js @ index.js:5fileEvaluate @ install.js:153require @ install.js:82meteorInstall.client.imports.parties-list.parties-list.js @ parties-list.ts:6fileEvaluate @ install.js:153require @ install.js:82meteorInstall.client.imports.parties-list.parties-list.ts @ parties-list.ts:1fileEvaluate @ install.js:153require @ install.js:82meteorInstall.client.app.js @ app.ts:6fileEvaluate @ install.js:153require @ install.js:82(anonymous function) @ parties.ts:22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced `meteor/accounts-base` module is a direct dependency of the [`accounts-password`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-password) package. Step 8 of the [Socially - A Meteor-Angular Tutorial App](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially) tutorial requires the installation of the `accounts-password` package, which will in turn install the `accounts-base` package. Make sure you've run the following:

```
meteor add accounts-password
```

To make sure it's installed, look in your `.meteor/versions` file for a matching `accounts-base@X.X.X` line.